# set email verification on bitnami Parse server from android studio

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, bitnami, parse-android-sdk

I have been searching day and night for a way to set email verification for my app with its server on Bitnami Parse Server(EC2). To no avail! All I could find was a client asking me to shift my app to back4App. But to switch my app to back4App only because I have no solution to email verification is ridiculous which is why i am stalling. Help Please!

I am looking for a tutorial or some detailed guide. I am not at all sure on how to download parse server mailgun.

Comment: Did you read the docs?

Comment: Yes but I couldn't understand effectively

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable HTTPS? Could you check this post? It might help you setting it up:

https://community.bitnami.com/t/parse-email-verification-issue/53354/

Comment: I'm so sorry I just tried what's in the link you sent. But I Must have done everything wrong. I am not at all sure now on how to download to mailgun parse server. I have putty. Should I install parse-server-mailgun on the server.ks using putty or in cmd. I'm a beginner and I don't understand. Sorry

Comment: Yes Antony, you will need to access the server using a SSH connection (putty) and then move to the Parse installation directory (`cd /opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs`) and run the npm command to install the tool (`npm install @parse/simple-mailgun-adapter`). After that, please configure the application following the information above.

Comment: After much research and thanks to you Jota Martos, I finally installed mailgun adapter but still cannot get to send a verification email. Something i would like to point out is initially it said my package.json was empty so i created a default package.json. Could it be there where i went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Access your server via Putty.
In the terminal go to directory htdocs by using command

```
$cd /opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs.
```

Here you will find one file package.json.
Open the file using vi and see whether it contains something or not

If it is empty then add {} to your package.json file
save it and run

```
$npm install @parse/simple-mailgun-adapter --save
```

After this open your server.js file set up your emailAdapter with appName and publicserverurl.

After this add this line to your server.js file

```
verifyUserEmails: true
```